# How to call and execute a SQL Server function in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following function in my SQL Server:

```
getMaxSL(paramter)
```

which will return a string value.

I have tried to call and execute this function from the Entity Framework in the following ways but did not work for me, instead it's returning the sql query itself.

```
var styleCode = (_dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<string>("Select dbo.getMaxSL(500)");
```

and

```
var styleCode = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select dbo.getMaxSL(500)");
```

**Would anyone tell me what are the best possible ways to call and execute a SQL Server function in Entity Framework??**

Answer (score 1):

Finally I myself found the solution as expected:

The codes should be as follows:

```
var styleCodeID = (_dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select dbo.getMaxSL(500)").FirstOrDefault();
```

and

```
var styleCode = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select dbo.getMaxSL(500)").FirstOrDefault();
```